# Intellij-idea module dependencies does not contain internal maven dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Problem: make module fails because **intellij fails to bring the dependencies of a snaphot dependency**.
 Building the module through maven **works fine** while it fails when trying to build it through make module.
When looking on the iml file, only the snapshot dependency exists but not the internal dependencies.

The local repository contains the jar and the pom file of  the dependency.

In the main pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.aa.bb</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact-dev</artifactId>
  <version>6.3.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
<\dependency>
```

This dependency exists in the local repository. The iml file does not contanis the dependencies listed in the pom file of this dependency.
**I make reimport from the pom file but it doesn't help.**
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the problem by:

```
mvn -X  -U idea:idea
```

This way I was able to see why it failed to parse the pom file and fix the problem in the pom file.

Comment: Any time your IDE/tool fails you, always revert to the mvn command line.  Always.  The -U directive you specified will force an update of SNAPSHOT dependencies.  You may want your build server's goals configured to always use that -U directive.  Good luck :)

Comment: Interesting. But the iml generated this was is not the same as the one generated by Intellij IDEA itself.